# Inheritance and initialization of attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance

```
class Email():

    def __init__(self, store_number):
        self.store_number = store_number

    def amethod(self):
        pass
```

What is the correct way to pass variables from a sub-class to a parent-class?
should I do:

```
class MoreSpecificEmail():

    def __init__(self, store_number):
        Email.__init__(self, store_number=store_number)

    def another_method(self):
        pass
```

or:

```
class MoreSpecificEmail():

    def __init__(self, store_number):
        self.store_number = store_number
        Email.__init__(self, store_number=self.store_number)
```

I have just been using different abbreviations of `store_number` in each sub-class to help clarify what's going on in my head.  I am sure that is the wrong way, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you currently have **isn't inheritance**; neither of your classes actually inherits from *anything*! Firstly, `Email` should be a *"new-style class"*, inheriting from `object`:

```
class Email(object):
          # ^ note inheritance from object

    def __init__(self, store_number):
        self.store_number = store_number

    def amethod(self):
        pass
```

Then `MoreSpecificEmail` should inherit from `Email` - as it doesn't have any additional instantiation parameters, it can just use the inherited `__init__` and doesn't need to define its own:

```
class MoreSpecificEmail(Email):
                      # ^ note inheritance from Email

    # note no need to define __init__

    def another_method(self):
        pass
```

For an example where there *are* additional `__init__` parameters, note that you should use `super` and rely on the superclass's `__init__` to assign the parameters it takes - you only need to assign the attributes that **don't** get handled by the superclass:

```
class MoreSpecificEmail(Email):

    def __init__(self, store_number, something_else):
        super(MoreSpecificEmail, self).__init__(store_number)
                                              # ^ pass it straight on
        self.something_else = something_else

    def another_method(self):
        pass
```

For more information, see [the Python class tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I checked out that tutorial, but in it they dont use SuperClass(object):, they just use SuperClass:  Is there a difference?

Comment: @MichaelBillingham there is in 2.x - the former creates a new-style class, the latter an old-style class. See e.g. https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/